# Adding Res files to Mac App Project

Tags: xcode, macos, file, cocoa

While adding any image file to Cocoa Application, I get the following two options:

> 1) Create groups for added folders.
>
> 2) Create folder references for any added folder.

What is the difference between the two options? Also what does "Copy items into the destination group's folder" do?

Scenario: I have already added the image that I need in the .xib file into the project directory physically. I have to include these images such that my release version of the project has these resources(images) some of which are called programmatically too!

File to show the dialog for adding an image@ https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj8hk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *always* choose to copy into the destination group's folder, especially for artwork. This is a matter of choice - when you leave this box unchecked, Xcode just adds a reference to the files in their current location. If you drag a .png in from the Desktop and don't choose to copy it, Xcode will essentially create an alias to the .png on the Desktop.

This could be exactly what you want - for example if you have an artwork folder for your app that walks stays in the same place and you don't want to bother re-dragging everything into Xcode every time you want it to update. The flip side of this, of course, is that if the file ever moves, Xcode's alias will stop working and you'll have missing files, which you'll the have to go hunt down.

For your other question, there's a great article on that here: http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2012/10/21/xcode-groups-vs-folder-references. I'll sum it up: Groups are for organization within Xcode, while folder references are like hierarchy within your app. They're also reflected in your app bundle after it's been compiled, while groups are flattened at compile time.

Comment: I always want all my resource files to be in the same folder as the project and not an absolute path on the desktop. Also does this break the build? I have first copied the resource files into a folder inside   finder then i dragged the folder from finder into Xcode so now I have added as the group. I am just not sure if this would break the build.